# Alternative of WCSF pattern

Tags: architecture, mvp, msdn, wcsf

As we all know [WCSF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648752.aspx)
 has been obselete from MSDN and they are no more supporting or updating it. 
My question is,  Is there any latest alternate for this.

So that we can go ahead with the latest architectural design pattern which is similar to WCSF and follows MVP pattern.